# TypeError: targetPlot.plugins is undefined

Tags: jquery, proxy, jqplot

I'm getting the error from the title. I'm trying to create proxy chart. As you can see in screenshot below, the controller is completely different then what I expect (it should be the mini version of the main plot; the variables line1, line2, line3 are same ). I'm attaching the whole code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.cursor.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.enhancedLegendRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.highlighter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>

  $(document).ready(function()
  {
        plot1023849675 = $.jqplot('plot_1023849675', [line1, line2, line3], 
        {                            
        axes:
        {           
            xaxis: {min: '1992-01-02', max: '2014-04-24',  'numberTicks' : 7,  renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer, tickOptions: {  formatString: '%d-%m-%y', angle: -30 }},
            yaxis: { tickOptions: {  formatString:'%.2f'}}
        },
        series:
        [
        {color:'red'  , label: 'Close'}, 
        {color:'green', label: 'Volumen',  yaxis: 'y2axis', linePattern: 'dashed'}, 
        {color:'blue' , label: 'Turnover', yaxis: 'y3axis', linePattern: 'dashed'}
        ],
        cursor: { show: true, showCursorLegend: true, showVerticalLine: true, tooltipAxisGroups: [['xaxis'], [ 'yaxis'], ['y2axis'], ['y3axis']]},
        legend: { show: true, placement: 'inside'   },
        seriesDefaults: 
        {
            showMarker:             false,
            lineWidth:              0.2,
            rendererOptions: { smooth: true, animation: {show: true  } }      
        },
        highlighter: 
        {
            show:                       true,
            showLabel:              true,
            tooltipAxes:            'y',
            showVerticalLine: true,
            sizeAdjust:             0.1 , 
            tooltipLocation : 'ne',        
        },
        axesDefaults: { fontFamily:'Helvetica', labelOptions:{ fontSize: "10px" },  tickOptions: {showGridline: false}}
    });


    controller_1023849675 = $.jqplot('controller_1023849675', [line1, line2, line3], {
        seriesDefaults:{ showMarker: false },
        series:
        [
        {color:'red'  , label: 'Close'}, 
        {color:'green', label: 'Volumen',  yaxis: 'y2axis', linePattern: 'dashed'}, 
        {color:'blue' , label: 'Turnover', yaxis: 'y3axis', linePattern: 'dashed'}
        ],
        cursor:{
        show:                       true,
        showTooltip:            false,
        zoom:                           true,
        constrainZoomTo:    'x'
        },
        axesDefaults: {
        RendererOptions: {
        alignTicks: true
      },
      axes:
        {           
            yaxis: { tickOptions: {  formatString:'%.2f'}}
        },
    }
  });

  $.jqplot.Cursor.zoomProxy(plot_1023849675, controller_1023849675);     
  $.jqplot._noToImageButton = true;
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct this line :

```
$.jqplot.Cursor.zoomProxy(plot_1023849675, controller_1023849675);
```

By this one :

```
$.jqplot.Cursor.zoomProxy(plot1023849675, controller_1023849675);
```

You need to give to the ZoomProxy function your targetPlot and your controllerPlot variables (I think there is a mistake with the id of the targetPlot (an additional underscore))

Comment: No I'm getting this error: TypeError: `plot.plugins.cursor.zoomCanvas is undefined`. And the controller plot still looks like teh same as in screenshot.

Comment: Check the name of your targetPlot and controllerPlot variable when defined and used. The underscore in your controllerPlot variable is it intentional (as it is absent in your targetPlot variable) ?

Comment: No, it was my mistake. I have changed the names. http://pastebin.com/sWySedYH <-- here the changed code. I still have no clue why the series are wrong... I use DateAxis. Could it be a porblem?